# FormatException for string to DateTime but not using DateTime C# Revision

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-phone-8.1

When I try to run my WindowsPhone8.1 app, I get the following error :

> An exception of type '`System.FormatException`' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Under troubleshooting tips it says

> When converting a string to `DateTime`, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the `DateTime` object.

However, I'm not using a `DateTime` in my code nor in my database for the entity that I'm retrieving.  I've double checked that I'm retrieving the correct entity and that it only contains `int` and `nvarchar` data types.
Here's my method that's throwing the exception:

```
public int stringToTeam(String Team, int start)
    {
        start = Team.IndexOf("TeamID", start) + 8;
        int end = Team.IndexOf(",", start); //start index correct
        //teamsListBox.Items.Add(end);
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Team.Substring(start, end - start)); //throws FormatException for string to DateTime
        //String id = Team.Substring(start, (end - start));
        teamsListBox.Items.Add("id is " + id);
        start = Team.IndexOf("TeamName", start) + 11;
        end = Team.IndexOf("\"", start);
        //teamsListBox.Items.Add(end);
        String name = Team.Substring(start, (end - start));
        teamsListBox.Items.Add("name is " + name);

        String city = Team.Substring(start, (end - start));
        teamsListBox.Items.Add("city is " + city);
        start = Team.IndexOf("TeamState", start) + 12;
        end = Team.IndexOf("\"", start);
        //teamsListBox.Items.Add(end);


        //creates a Teams model obj with values pulled from string and adds it to static list of objs in Teams model
        //teamsListBox.Items.Add(Teams.TeamsList.Count);
        Teams newTeam = new Teams(id, name, city);
        Teams.TeamsList.Add(newTeam);
        //teamsListBox.Items.Add(Teams.TeamsList.Count);
        //teamsListBox.Items.Add(newTeam.ToString());

        end += 4;
        if (end <= Team.Length)
        {
            return end;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

The problem seems to be coming from this line:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Team.Substring(start, end - start));
```

I've used the exact same code for my `Bars` entity, and it works just fine, so I know that this line correctly converts a `string` to an `int`. But why is it saying I have a `FormatException` for a `DateTime`, if I'm not using a `DateTime` in this file's code or in the corresponding database table?

REVISION:

Thanks for the help everyone.  I was able to fix that exception with your help.  However, now I have another problem.  I can't seem to get values to print into my GUI.  Here's the method that calls the stringToTeams method above:

```
public async void GetTeams()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            teamsListBox.Items.Add("using block entered");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://nflff.azurewebsites.net");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            teamsListBox.Items.Add("client's defaultrequestheaders done");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/teams");//not getting past here
            teamsListBox.Items.Add("right after response"); //not printing
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                teamsListBox.Items.Add("if entered");
                //IList<Teams> Teams = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Teams>>();
                string teams = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                int start = 0;
                while (start != -1)
                {
                    start = stringToTeam(teams, start); //throwing exception inside stringToTeams, which isn't being called anywhere else
                }
            }
            teamsListBox.Items.Add(Teams.TeamsList.Count);
            foreach (var team in Teams.TeamsList)
            {
                teamsListBox.Items.Add(team.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

The first 2 test messages are getting printed to the GUI; however, the "right after response" message and any message or value after that isn't printing.  What really confuses me is that the code in stringToTeam is being executed, and that method is only being called in GetTeams.  Furthermore, the code for GetTeams is exactly the same as the code for GetBars (except with bars replaced with teams), and my bars code works fine.  Any ideas?  Thanks again for all your continued help. I'm using a SQL database connected to a Web API service.  My backend is .NET.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @mason "An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code" is the exact message.  TeamID is an int in the database.

Comment: Is there an inner exception? Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger to see what `start` and `end` are and make sure they're valid, and that the value represented at that substring is a valid int?

Comment: At a glance, I would say that the result of the `Substring` contains some non-numeric character (maybe an off-by-one error?).  What are the values of 'Team` and `start` when this exception is thrown?

Comment: Try using [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and verify that the return value is true. Can you print `Team.Substring(start, end - start)` and check what it contains.

Comment: @jeffkempf What are the return value of your `Team.Substring(start, end - start)` and your `CurrentCulture` exactly? Without these informations, it is not possible to answer your question.

Comment: @mason When I ran the debugger and inserted a breakpoint to check the local values, I realized that my start index was off.  Thanks for bringing this up.  I got so caught up in the fact that the error message mentioned DateTime, that I couldn't look past that.  The local values are correct now, but I can't get them to print onto my GUI.  I'll make an edit to include the code.

Comment: If you have a new question you should post it as a new question rather than building on an existing question whose title no longer represents what you're asking.

Comment: @CraigW. Thanks.  I'll make sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions.  After I fixed the start and end index values, everything started working correctly.  As for the printing issue, this might sound embarrassing, but I forgot to disable the breakpoint from my testing.  Once I did that, the code worked.  Thanks again.